# Convert _Assembly to VARIANT

Tags: c++, clr

I have a CLR hosting application that I'm trying to make it support WPF.

I attempted to set a value of a field to `_Assembly` but the problem is that I have to pass a variable of type `VARIANT`.

This is the C# code that I'm trying to convert to C++:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(data);
...
field.SetValue(null, assembly); // I'm attempting to do that in C++
```

Here is what I did:

```
_AssemblyPtr pAssembly = NULL;

...

hr = AppDomain->Load_3(sa, &pAssembly);

...

CComVariant obj;
BindingFlags bFlags = (BindingFlags)(BindingFlags_SetField | BindingFlags_NonPublic | BindingFlags_Static);
hr = fieldInfo->SetValue(obj, CComVariant(pAssembly), bFlags, NULL, NULL);
```

It fails at `fieldInfo->SetValue` and more accurate at the 2nd argument which is supposed to be of type `VARIANT`. Error: `hr = E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid.`

If I set the second argument to `CComVariant(NULL)`, it doesn't fail but I need to put the `_Assembly` there.

Any idea how I can deal with the problem?

Comment: CComVariant(pAssembly.GetInterfacePtr()), probably.